# Defined PHP function returns function undefined

Tags: php

I have a functions.php page with some functions, it is required in the default.php page which is required by all my other pages (index.php) at the first line.

index.php (1st line after `<?php`

```
require("includes/default.php");
```

default.php

```
<?php
//mysql
require("templates.php");
require("functions.php");
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function rating_format($num) {
    if ($num > 0) {
        return "+" . $num;
    }
    elseif ($num < 0) {
        return "-" . $num;
    }
    else {
        return $num;
    }
}

function thumbnail_url($value) {
    if ($value == "") {
        return "no_favicon.png";
    }
    else {
        return $value;
    }
}
?>
```

I use both functions defined in functions.php in index.php. However, only the second function seems to be defined. Whenever trying to use the first function, it spits out an function undefined error.

I've rearranged the code several times and don't know what is wrong with it. The function is defined before I even use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Debug with `print_r(get_defined_functions())` where the error occurs.

Comment: Is there only one file named `functions.php` in your project? Make sure `functions.php` is on the include path or use absolute paths when including / requiring.

Comment: My custom defined functions: [user] => Array ( [0] => page_header [1] => page_footer [2] => thumbnail_url ). Does not have 'rating_format'.

Comment: @Phil Brown, there is only one file. I can confirm it is included correctly.

Comment: Maybe an other `thumbnail_url` somewhere and functions.php is not correctly included ? Try `print_r(get_included_files())`

Comment: Thanks @Loic Fevrier, that fixed it. There was a mysterious functions.php file in my base directory, removed it and success. I will use absolute paths from now on. PHP seems to go to the base directory to look for the file, then go to the file directory.

Comment: @Sliced Toast - So there *was* more than one `functions.php`? PHP bases all require / include paths off the `include_path` (see `get_include_path()`) which usually includes `.`, being the current working directory. When you start nesting includes, this CWD is set with the parent file. If you want to know the directory of the current script, use `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Yes, I must have committed the file to the wrong directory a while back, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the name of the `functions.php` file to something more unique / less generic, like `rating.fcns.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by replacing the includes with the actual code for the time being, just to see if the issue is with your includes or your functions.